# Why is my menu going off the screen, but its still visible?

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I'm currently creating the menu sidebar for mobile devices and when I hide the menu, it ends up going off the screen, but still visible once you swipe to the right.
[screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9OA5.png)

Also, feel free to point out any issues in my code since I'm pretty new to web development!

```
      <nav>
        <a href="index.html"> LOGO</a>
        <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark icon" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars icon" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
      </nav>
```

```
@media(max-width: 700px){
  .text-box h1{
    font-size:30px;
  }
  .nav-links ul li{
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .nav-links{
    position: absolute;
    background:#337195;
    height:100vh;
    width:250px;
    top:0;
    right:-300px;
    text-align:left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  .icon { 
    display: block;
    color:white;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .nav-links ul{
    padding: 30px;
  }
  .nav-links ul li::after{
    width: 100%;
    background:white; 
  }

}
```

Javascript of menu show/hide animation

```
<script>
  var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks")

  function showMenu(){
    navLinks.style.right = "0"
  }
  function hideMenu(){
    navLinks.style.right = "-300px"
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe increase `right:-300px;` to something much larger, to make sure it's well out of the viewport.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that if I do that, the user is still able to scroll to the side and see the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is enough context to answer the question to your specific situation BUT this is what I would do based on what I can see.

It looks like there isn't anything hiding the navigation element (`<nav>`).

In **open state** add `display: block;` to the navigation

```
nav {
  display: block;
}
```

During **close state** change the css to `display: none;` to the parent navigation

```
nav {
   display: none;
}
```

There are a number of ther ways of achiveing this, but I'd start here.

Comment: I used some vanilla javascript (I added the code in at the top) for a sliding animation on the menu so if I change the display for nav in css, that renders the transition obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `overflow: hidden;` on the parent container.